# "id" and "id name" get different group id

Tags: permissions, users, groups

My ubuntu user name is **lr**. I use **usermod** to change my group id

```bash
lr@amax$ sudo usermod lr -g ob
```

When  I check with command **id**

```bash
lr@amax$ id
uid=1004(lr) gid=1008(lr) groups=1008(lr)
```

however when I use command **id lr**

```bash
lr@amax$ id lr
uid=1004(lr) gid=2002(ob) groups=2002(ob)
```

The gid and groups are both different. I can't access a folder owned by ob groups.

After more tests, I found that when login in with Xshell or Powershell, the gid and groups id is modified. But in [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), even when I reopen the work folder, the gid and groups id are unchanged. Maybe It is a bug of [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

I restart my PC and reopen VScode, connecting my server through the Remote-SSH plugin. I got the info

```bash
 lr@amax$ id
uid=1004(lr) gid=1008(lr) groups=1008(lr)
 lr@amax$ id lr
uid=1004(lr) gid=2002(ob) groups=2002(ob)
```

But in Xshell, the problem is gone.

```bash
lr@amax$ id
uid=1004(lr) gid=2002(ob) groups=2002(ob)
lr@amax$ id lr
uid=1004(lr) gid=2002(ob) groups=2002(ob)
```

Comment: When I login in through the terminal in VScode, I got the right answer.
In VScode terminal:   lr@amax$ ssh lr@ip

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't logged out and logged back in, then `id` is showing your *current* information for your login session.

The query of `id lr` is querying the actual system information for what the group IDs are and verifies that against current system user information (and NOT your current session information).

If you have logged out and then logged back in, then something's broken.  However, it's more likely you haven't yet, so you're seeing `id` for your current session and `id lr` for the actual information that `usermod` revised.